# Problema con llenado de un combo de manera dinámica

Tags: jquery, json

Tengo un problema al llenar un combo con datos de una tabla,
por un lado tengo el siguiente código

Y por otro lado tengo el encargado de realizar la consulta con php

```php
if ($accion == 8) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM estados order by Estado";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$result) {
        die('Query Failed ' .$query .' ' . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    $json = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $json[] = array(
            'a' => $row['Estado']
        );
    }
    $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
    echo $jsonstring;
}
```

Pero al checar mediante la console.log no me regresa ningún valor pero si me retorna el siguiente error

```javascript
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

llenaCmbEstado  @   verificacion.js:484
```

Gracias.

Comment: Ya cheque la consulta y arroja resultados, si regreso un valor sin json lo manda pero al usar la instrucción $jsonstring = json_encode($json); ya no me regresa nada

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución por si alguien presenta el mismo problema, el detalle esta que los valores que regresa la consulta venían con caracteres especiales (acentos, ñ, etc.) por lo que solo lo que cambio fue el código en php quedando de la siguiente manera.

```
if ($accion == 8) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM estados order by Estado";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(!$result) {
    die('Query Failed ' .$query .' ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}
$json = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $json[] = array(
        'a' => utf8_encode($row['Estado'])
    );
}
$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
```

}